# access DB::select() return query in laravel view

Tags: mysql, laravel, controller, return-value

i'm new in laravel. i want to ask is there any other option to access variable in view without using foreach since the return query will always return a single row value.

this is my controller function.

```
public function publ(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $user = DB::select("select u.name as name, ut.name as type, ui.info as info from user u
    join info ui on ui.id = u.infoid
    join usertype ut on u.utype = ut.id
    where u.id = ?", [$id]);

    if ($user != null) {
        return view('index', ['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

i used this to access it on view.

```
@foreach($user as $u)
    {{ $u->name }}
@endforeach
```

it works but i just curious about other options.

i've tried using `{{ $user[0]['name'] }}` but it shows error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are **NOT** using Query Builder or Eloquent, you are doing a direct query on the Connection. This will return an array of `stdClass` objects. `stdClass` objects do not have any "array access" as they are just base level objects; you have to interact with them as objects (accessing properties) not as an array (accessing elements).

Assuming you actually get a result the first result would be accessed as:

```
$user[0]
```

The properties of that object would be accessed via the property notation:

```
$user[0]->name
```

These are not Models. Eloquent Models implement `ArrayAccess` which allows them to be "used" as arrays (using array notation). This is not something that is default for objects.